# How to make a proprietary synchronous web service api available for asynchronous usage (async/await)?

Tags: c#, async-await, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

**Specific Question:** 
How to make a proprietary synchronous web service api available for  asynchronous usage (async/await)?

**Background:**
I am currently migrating a .NET Windows Service to use the **async/await** pattern. The service is polling the Microsoft Exchange Server a lot via the use of **Exchange Web Services Managed API**, in order to extract and automatically process some mails. Since the amount of mails is increasing quickly (around 10k/day), I am ask to improve it's throughput. Since the **wait time is basically IO related not CPU**, I thought it would be beneficial to use async/await and await the calls to Exchange. Currently the **EWS Managed API** does provide only some asynchronous operations (i.e. all Folder or EmailMessage related operations are synchronous).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too broad and will be closed.  Please ask a *specific* question that has a *specific* answer.

Comment: Please show some effort to solve this, then ask questions. Maybe learning more theory of parallel and async programming will also help. You mix those two terms too much here.

Comment: Look in the Task class. You have Task.Run() and other functions. Read up on async programming and be sure not to use blocking methods. Very broad answer ;)

Comment: If you're spending most of your time waiting on I/O, and cannot concurrently call the Exchange server, then how exactly do you expect to increase throughput?

Comment: @roryap How do you know it will be closed? Why not instead help OP clarify his question?

Comment: Many thanks. It seems like I have to take some more time to dig deeper into async/await. @Stephen Cleary: I still want it to be a single threaded application. While a call to exchange is made, the application is able to process some further work, i.e. accessing the next mailbox to extract mails from.

Comment: @Fabe the EWS API **does** provide asynchronous methods, using the older APM pattern with BeginXXX,EndXXX mehtods. You need to use a TaskCompletionSource to convert these to Tasks

Comment: Please reopen the question. This isn't a broad question, the OP made the wrong assumption there are no asynchronous methods even though there are. He needs to use a TaskCompletionSource but it's impossible to post a sample in a comment! It may well be a duplicate but the issue is very specific.

Comment: Converting APM to Tasks is covered in [Wrapping APM operations in a Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi! Edited my questions in order to follow the rules. Can you please unhold my question?

Comment: Hi Panagoitis! EWS Managed API only offers some APM style methods. Most of them are synchronous, i.e. Folder.Bind and EmailMessage.Move.

Answer (score 3):

> Specific Question: How can I call an synchronous API asynchronously?

Wrong question, IMO. Calling a synchronous API asynchronously will not help throughput at all. In this case, it will actually cause some unnecessary overhead, (very) slightly *reducing* throughput.

> I still want it to be a single threaded application. While a call to exchange is made, the application is able to process some further work, i.e. accessing the next mailbox to extract mails from.

You can't have it both ways. If the Exchange API is synchronous, then by definition it *must* block a thread while waiting for and reading the next mail message.

It sounds like you *might* benefit from using TPL Dataflow, so you could have your main thread reading from Exchange and posting to a Dataflow block, and allow the block to process messages on a background thread. This would only improve your throughput if your assumption about spending most of your time reading from Exchange is wrong.

A dataflow solution could look like this:

```
ActionBlock<string> _block;

void MainLoop()
{
  _block = new ActionBlock<string>(ProcessMessage);
  while (true)
  {
    var message = ReadFromExchange();
    _block.Post(message);
  }
}

void ProcessMessage(string message)
{
  ...
}
```

Note that this kind of queue-for-processing-later approach can get overwhelmed if `ReadFromExchange` is often faster than `ProcessMessage`.

Comment: EWS provides APS-style methods

Comment: Hi Stephen! I read your blogposts concerning async/await, they were very helpful. I am afraid TPL Dataflow is no option, since the reading from the Exchange Server (ReadFromExchange) takes most of the time. Currently I am thinking to build some kind of throtteling and use Task.Run to access each mailbox in a dedicated thread. This way I can gain at least some performance benefit by parallel reading, even Task.Run should only be used only for CPU bound work.